# Running Net Core Api and MongoDb in the same container

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have a requirement to create a Net Core Api running in a docker container. Typically, I would link that to another container running MongoDb and run them both in the same Docker CLI together but seperate containers.

However, for this project I need to embed MongoDb inside the actual API project container and access it from the API as a local implementation (to that container).

I’ve been able to create the container for the API and part of that Dockerfile installs MongoDb - but I cant work out what my connection string for MongoDb needs to be - given that its running inside the container too. Could someone give me some pointers?

Comment: Can you add your actual Dockerfile and the connection string used?

Comment: If your MongoDb is running in the same container, then the hostname in the connection string from your API should be `localhost`.

Comment: You have to check if mongodb is actually started, what do you use to start both process ?

Comment: Got it! it was a combination of both comments from HansKilian & Mr_Thorynque - I hadn't created the default user and started MongoDb - thanks!